# Generic XSLT for parsing XML to pipe delimited value

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the below XML and need to convert it to pipe delimited values. The constraint is the solution needs to be a generic one.

```
<Root>
<Element>
    <Value1>1</Value1>
    <Value2>2</Value2>
    <Value3/>
    <Value4/>  
</Element>
<Element>
    <Value1>1</Value1>
    <Value2>2</Value2>
    <Value3>3</Value3>
    <Value4>4</Value4>
</Element>
<Element>
    <Value1>1</Value1>
    <Value2/>
    <Value3>3</Value3>
    <Value4>4</Value4>
</Element>
</Root>
```

The expected output is :

```
1|2||
1|2|3|4
1||3|4
```

So far [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14919061/xslt-looping-using-xslvariable) link was useful for me but even after tweaking it I couldnot get the tag names dynamically. Is there any way I can get pass this?

Comment: You can use `*` as a wild card. Post your attempt, if you want more specific advice.

Comment: There are certain function associated with tag name in the link given. I replaced hard coded values with *. It is printing the tag values but not in a single pipe delimited value.

Comment: Please show your code, so that we can reproduce your problem. I have no idea what "*certain function associated with tag name*" means.

Comment: can u please check the XSLT 1.0 solution (answer 2)  in this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14919061/xslt-looping-using-xslvariable)?

Comment: @ArunRaj, why should *we* check that answer?  It appears complete, and the question provides the relevant XML input.  Check it yourself.

Comment: @JohnBollinger My question is different. My XML is different than the xml in the link.

Comment: @michael.hor257k The solution has some functions with tag name eg:
`Value[position() &lt;= $count]`
where `Value` is a tag name. I am looking for a generic solution with no hard coded child tag names

Comment: If you want to process all child elements, then, as already indicated in the first comment to your question, you can use `*` instead of e.g. `Value`.

Comment: I tried it..but all values are coming in new lines and no `\` delimiter is appending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to transform all child elements of the root elements into lines containing the values of all grand child elements separated then the following should do:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:param name="lf" select="'&#10;'"/>
    <xsl:param name="delim" select="'|'"/>

    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*/*">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$lf"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*/*/*">
        <xsl:if test="position() > 1">
            <xsl:value-of select="$delim"/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Perfect. Better than my answer below. Totally generic one. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

After too much work around I found my own solution.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select="Element">
   <xsl:for-each select="*">
    <xsl:value-of select="." /> <xsl:if test="position() != last()">|<xsl:text/></xsl:if>
    
   </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Are you sure you have `<xsl:template match="/"><xsl:for-each select="Element">`? In your question you have a `Root` element not accounted for in your XSLT.

Comment: I am new to XSLT. My code above somehow was working but need to specify the first child node. Your code is completely generic and perfect for my use. I am using your xslt now.